# "not" operator or negation in Prolog

Tags: prolog, negation

### Background

I need to write a relation power(P) that looks through a list and decides if all but one element of P is zero.

Here is what I have:

```
%I have a relation called zero(P) which decides if every element is zero.

power([H|T]) :- H is not zero,  %The current element is non zero, the tail is all zero.
                zero(T).         
power([0|T]) :- power(T).       %The current element is zero, 
                                %but the tail has a non zero element in it.
```

Some resources suggest using the cut operator (!), which controls backtracking and I don't think that is what I'm looking for.

I have also come across the not provable operator (\+), which seems to swap the result (is not provable returns yes), and I don't think that's what I want either.

I did find the [Prolog Dictionary](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#negation), but I can't figure out what "not" means or how to use it (as you can imagine, Ctrl+F finds many instances of " not ").

### Question

How can I say 'H is not zero' in prolog?

**EDIT** The list is a list of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your argument is a list of numbers, you can simply use [arithmetic operators](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%274.27.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/arith.html%27%29%29):

```
power([H|T]):- H =\= 0, zero(T).
power([H|T]):- H =:= 0, power(T).
```

---

In general, you could also write `\+ (H=0)`. That means, `H` can not be unified with `0`.

The question is, what do you want to happen if this predicate is called with a list that is not a list of numbers. The above code would cause an error. If you want it to just fail in such cases, then it can be defined as

```
power([H|T]):- \+(H=0), zero(T).
power([H|T]):- H=0, power(T).
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Super simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution using 'not provable' operator:

```
  zero([]).
  zero([0|T]) :- zero(T).

  power([H|T]) :- \+ zero(H), zero(T).         
  power([0|T]) :- power(T).
```

Comment: you have an error here: `zero(H)` is called with a number, but expects a list. :)

Comment: Do you suggest `power([H|T]):- \+ zero([H]), zero(T).` instead? It appears that the zero relation accepts a number in place of a list as well, and that works fine.

Comment: Nevermind, `zero(T)` always takes the tail of a list which is always a list (even if it is the empty list). My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

zero/1 seems a rather specialized predicate. If you want to learn about more idiomatic (advanced?) Prolog, consider a 'one liner' definition, based on library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)):

```
power(L) :- include(=\=(0), L, [_]).
```

test:

```
?- power([0,99,0,0]).
true.

?- power([0,99,0,1]).
false.
```

Of course, I can't imagine why you named such predicate 'power'...

Comment: This is a big problem for me with Prolog: the available teaching material (online) as a rule uses non-idiomatic solutions. One can find mainly trivial problems solved non-optimally using a seemingly random subset of Prolog. I wish there would be a Prolog Tutorial, "Python Tutorial" style, for SWI-Prolog, showing us how the current implementations is supposed to be used according to its developers and power-users.

Comment: @Boris: Prolog is a bit impeded by its *long* heritage (it's almost a C contemporary), and by implementations' divergence. There is some effort going on to help beginners, but I think that StackOverflow approach it's the better available right now. I was thinking of integrating resources from SO in a small IDE I'm working on, to integrate the good SWI-Prolog documentation with some use cases.

Comment: I perfectly understand the difficulties. The SWI-Prolog documentation is indeed very good. Still, considering the amount of effort that Jan Wielemaker and others are putting into the implementation, it is almost sad that there is not a decent tutorial for it (not on Prolog in general, or logical programming: simply on the SWI implementation). You and some others provide invaluable help for newcommers here on SO, but unfortunately, much of it is undone by the knuckle-headed approach to Prolog teaching in most universities.

Comment: As a small example, the solution to OP's original problem that you suggested is probably considered unacceptable. The professor will cite didactic reasons, and this is just silly.

Comment: @CapelliC I named the predicate power because the list is a list of coefficients representing a polynomial, eg 1 + x + 4x^2 + 5x^3 is represented by [1,1,4,5]. I need to find a simple power of x, i.e. only one of the elements in the list is non-zero. I didn't explain that part because my question was much simpler than that. Thank you for your efficient solution, I will look into the link you provided.